# How to use google login authentication library

Tags: react-native, expo, google-oauth, google-api-js-client, appauth

I am following tutorial but library for google login is deprecated, I have followed the advice for using the new library from and yet I get the error "can't find variable auth" screen shot:
[image: error being shown can't find variable auth]

code: LoginScreen.js:

```
    import GoogleLogin from '../hooks/Auth';
    import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    import React from 'react';
    import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth";
    import * as Google from "expo-auth-session/providers/google";
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

    const LoginScreen = () => {
        const { signInWithGoogle } = useAuth();

        const { request, GoogleLogin } = Auth();

      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Login to the app</Text>
          <Button 
          disabled={!request}
          title='login' onPress={GoogleLogin} />
        </View>
       )
    };

    export default LoginScreen;
```

Auth.js:

```
    import * as React from "react";
    import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
    import { Button } from "react-native";
    import * as Google from "expo-auth-session/providers/google";
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

    WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

    const GoogleLogin = () => {
      const navigation = useNavigation();
      const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
        expoClientId:
          "236293699216-bst43767un873mcddmmrpgf4v2h088jd.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        iosClientId:
         "236293699216-6jdpm0rd6kn5d0qlbh1vgva5afgbqgib.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        webClientId:
          "236293699216-9a0nknjdq7ie79h40iubg0tddokgogfv.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      });

      const asyncAuthRequest = async () => {
        if (response?.type === "success") {
         const { authentication } = response;
           // await AsyncStorage.setItem("accessTocken", "hihi");

            navigation.navigate("Root");
        }
        };

        useEffect(() => {
        asyncAuthRequest();
      }, [response]);

      return (
        <Button
          disabled={!request}
          title="Login"
          onPress={() => {
            promptAsync();
          }}
        />
      );
    };

    export default GoogleLogin;
```

I would've been using signInWithGoogle from useAuth.js but the library for that has moved to expo-auth-session which is what GoogleLogin is using.

Any advice on what I am doing wrong